# How to JavaScript object to Kotlin class?

Tags: javascript, class, kotlin, kotlin-js-interop, kotlin-js

I want to get a JavaScript object loaded into a Kotlin class.
As a safety check, I need to verify that the Kotlin object is actually the class I’ve created because some JavaScript code parts are not my design.
I need the JavaScript to return correctly, but I cannot verify the Kotlin class.

e.g.

JavaScript object

```
<script id="myJS">
function MyClass(id, name){
    var obj = {};
    obj.id = id;
    obj.name = name;

    return obj;
}
var myClass = MyClass(0, "name_0");
</script>
```

Kotlin class

```
class MyClass(
            val id: Int,
            val name: String
)
```

I use this Kotlin code to get JavaScript object on Kotlin.

```
val myJS: dynamic = document.getElementById("myJS")
val myClass: MyClass = JSON.parse<MyClass>(JSON.stringify(myJS.myClass))//get JavaScript object
println(myClass.id)//success output "0"
println(myClass.name)//success output "name_0"

println(myClass is MyClass)//but check class this output "false"
```

How can I verify the JavaScript object is the created Kotlin class?

Answer (score 2):

Use `JSON.parse` from [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library instead of `JSON.parse` from Kotlin/JS standard library.

[JSON](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.js/-j-s-o-n/index.html#json) from Kotlin standard library is just a view around JavaScript [JSON object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) . So `JSON.parse` creates regular JS object without any information about Kotlin type.

Its fine to use it with [external](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-interop.html#external-modifier) classes that can't be type-checked. But your `MyClass` is a regular class.

Objects constructed from regular Kotlin classes have special metadata which is essential for type checks `myClass is MyClass` and reflection `myClass::class == MyClass::class`. And [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) library creates these full-featured Kotlin objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this check :

```
myClass::class == MyClass::class
```

Comment: same output "false"

Comment: println(myClass::class)//this output "class Any"

Comment: println(MyClass::class)//this output "class MyClass"

Comment: Ah, maybe try ::class.java and do the comparison that way. If that doesn’t work you might want to use something like Moshi https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/advanced-json-parsing-techniques-using-moshi-and-kotlin-daf56a7b963d

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
class MyClass(val id: Int, val name: String) {
    constructor(obj: dynamic): this(obj.id, obj.name)

    override fun toString(): String = 
        "${this.id} ${this.name}"
}

fun main() {

    val obj  = js("{}")
    obj.id   = 1
    obj.name = "Mike"

    val myObj = MyClass(obj)
    println(myObj)
    println(myObj is MyClass)
}
```

Comment: I try if then obj.id="Mike" . It will be println(myObj is MyClass) output "true". But,  println(myObj.id) output "Mike" and println(myObj.id is Int) output "false". I try if then or obj.id=null .  It will be println(myObj is MyClass) output "true". But,  println(myObj.id) output null and println(myObj.id is Int) output "false".

Comment: Change MyClass primary ctor to null aware fields:

    class MyClass(val id: Int?, val name: String?)

But will have to null check your class members...

Comment: p.s. what compiler version are you using, which options?

Comment: Kotlin Compiler Version 1.3